Can I use same subdomain to serve both ColudFront, S3 and Apache?
I'm trying to setting up a application on S3 and CloudFront and the frontend application is using Flutter.
Frontend
I have managed to deployed S3 and CloudFront successfully.
Let's say the domain dev.demo.thiha.com. The SSL is issued from AWS Cert Manager.
Backend
Backend is implemented with Laravel and it have admin dashboard.
Let's say dev.demo.thiha.com/admin/login and endpoint to serve Frontend is dev.demo.thiha.com/api, it's plan to serve from Laravel backend.
I'm planing to setup Apache for that.
Question:
Can I use same subdomain to serve both ColudFront and Apache?
And for admin/login route, how can I serve from Apache? What is the best way to do my scenario ?

In case someone have same issue as mine, I used Lambda Edge function to do redirect part and this function is called via cloudfront's new behavior for the path pattern /admin/*
Update CloudFront Behaviors:

Go to the CloudFront console.
Select your distribution and go to the
"Behaviors" tab. Edit or create a new behavior for the path pattern
/admin/*
Set the origin to your Apache server.
Attach the Lambda@Edge function to the behavior’s origin request event using the ARN of the published version.

